# How do you ORDER BY using the FORMAT function

Tags: sql-server

I am using the `FORMAT(value, 'C')` function to show dollar amounts in my result set. The data type of my `value` is numeric.

When set the `ORDER BY` to sort by this function, it appears to sort by the first digit of the dollar amount, so $9.00 comes before $8,500.00.

How do you `ORDER BY` the `FORMAT(value,'C')`?

Comment: Don't; format the data in your presentation layer, not the RDBMS. Return just the value of `value` in your data, and order by that. `FORMAT` returns a `varchar` value, and a `varchar` and a numerical data type are **nothing** alike. `10` is greater than `2`, but `'$2'` is **greater than** `'$10'`. This is because the numbers are being ordered "alphabetically" and as `'2'` is greater than `'1'`; which is the first different character, it therefore means that  `'2'` is also greater than `'10'`

Comment: Just **DO NOT** apply `FORMAT()` to the `value` column in your `ORDER BY` - just order by the actual, numerical value

Answer (score 0):

What is your data type for value? Is it Money? If so, you should be able to just Order by value without using format.

If its string, you can use the Replace function to ignore dollar/comma and then convert the type using CAST (Use TRY_CAST - returns NULL if CAST fails)

```
    ORDER BY TRY_CAST( replace(replace(value,'$',''),',','') as float)
```

Comment: There's no reason to cast back to a numeric type. Just use the original value.

Comment: Certainly, as well, for a monetary value I would never recommend a imprecise data type like `float`.

Comment: Correct, no need to use the cast unless its the data type is varchar.